# Type trait: Check if class have specific function (maybe inherit)

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I know that there are many possible ways to detect if a class has a specific function but non of them really work for my exact case. My current implementation to check for the correct member function works, except for inherit functions.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>                                                                
class HasFoo {                                                                                 
    template <typename U, int (U::*)(float)>                                  
      struct Check;                                                                 

    template <typename U>                                                       
      static std::true_type Test(Check<U, &U::foo> *);                 

    template <typename U>                                                           
      static std::false_type Test(...);                                               

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(Test<T>(0))::value;                    
};

struct A {
  int foo(float);
};

struct B : public A {
};

struct C {
  unsigned int foo(double);
};

struct D {
  static int foo(float);
};

static_assert(HasFoo<A>::value, "A should have foo.");
static_assert(HasFoo<B>::value, "B should inherit foo from A.");

static_assert(!HasFoo<C>::value, "C should not have foo.");
static_assert(!HasFoo<D>::value, "Ds static foo should be false.");
```

[Live example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPgCgq0EBbLKIu9bBMI%2B5AFQqQGChwkaLHiJ4qtCJkySABKyAYgHtVSAN6SduvfoNUAkHUbM6qTDk7ckAVQA0ScGiQAKOwC5PAKgCUbgBmUKosfvwGkcYCZIQwEK4AwgAWCBAA1gDckTm5kjQmDEwsyGzWXMh2EXk1OtFIsSwgEA1ocN5xeFa8CLFuKWnpKI5IAGRenoHq/P7ZhsamxRZlHBX21bWb%2BUYxaE0tse2TRFBkXexIPL1obgB0935zWzU0WDAARlDNnsaNaM1ICCqMCxBAADywBCQ73UUCQADcTjBkABeJCIaDdNxXWIoPhuAAMfj83kRsAQTyiAF9MjRYgR4q4AIJaKgCFxIKaqIIhMK0ml0uIJJAAISQniQb0%2BAJZmioAqo9MZSESrIEMBBIAA5mAEHBnGBXFy3HBVB8oAhHvLaYqha4ACJq1r7A1G9Q80JoK0Kv7NXCyM4EG5KMhqVQoJkUUlIhBOABELLIyTNUH1ySI8OQXNucatvog/rkCCDbhDYZQIqjnjJyPjYqTKf14FSBFInPUnIIqnoSCZOattv2hcDNwAhGX1ChElWa7GkHHVQ2YKmkGBVK505n26p%2B7T88Pi2OJ%2BH7TOY/H7fJ89uGsnl/r3lmTmdd0AA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

This implementation does not work for the static_assert of B.

An inacceptable workaround would be to check for:

```
template <typename U, int (U::A::*)(float)>
struct Check;                 |
                              |- add base class
```

But there I would have to know the base class and this should be avoided.

Does anyone have an idea how to check also for derivated functions?

**Edit:**
The type trait should also work if no Foo at all exist.

```
struct E {};
static_assert(!HasFoo<E>::value, "E does not have foo.");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one old school **C++03** way of doing it. Typically it can be used as a utility and get it molded for any *method or variable*.

```
#define HasMember(NAME) \
  template<class Class, typename Type = void> \
  struct HasMember_##NAME \
  { \
    typedef char (&yes)[2]; \
    template<unsigned long> struct exists; \
    template<typename V> static yes Check (exists<sizeof(static_cast<Type>(&V::NAME))>*); \
    template<typename> static char Check (...); \
    static const bool value = (sizeof(Check<Class>(0)) == sizeof(yes)); \
  }; \
  template<class Class> \
  struct HasMember_##NAME<Class, void> \
  { \
    typedef char (&yes)[2]; \
    template<unsigned long> struct exists; \
    template<typename V> static yes Check (exists<sizeof(&V::NAME)>*); \
    template<typename> static char Check (...); \
    static const bool value = (sizeof(Check<Class>(0)) == sizeof(yes)); \
  }
```

Instantiate:

```
HasMember(Foo);
```

**Usage**:

```
HasMember_Foo<B>::value  // without type (but then no overload allowed)
HasMember_Foo<C, int (C::*)(float)>::value  // needs type
```

Note that, here I am providing two `HasMember_Foo`s, 1 with type and 1 without type. They are generalized for any type (not just specific to `int (X::*)(float)`). If there is no type mentioned, then the class must have only 1 such method (without overload). Hence, it's always safer to mention the type; As you have done in your question, the specific type is `int (X::*)(float)`. BTW, this also can be included using another macro.
Without such extra macro, in case of `class C` and `class D`, you may have to specify the type of the method.

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/YO2z4O) with your code.

---

Here it's assumed that whichever class member (function or variable) is chosen, must be `public` scoped. i.e. If `X::foo` is `private` then this solution will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it (work for your 4 test cases, did not test it intensively though), thanks @Jarod42 for the improvement (see initial answer at the end):

```
template <typename T>
int call_foo (int (T::*)(float));

template <typename C>
std::true_type has_foo(decltype(call_foo(&C::foo)));

template <typename C>
std::false_type has_foo (...);    

template<typename T>
using HasFoo = decltype(has_foo<T>(0));
```

The problem with your code was that you were expecting `U::*` whereas `&B::foo` is `A::*` (not `B::*`). Here I let the compiler choose the value of `T` by using implicit type deduction so I don't run into such issue.

The code works as follow:

- If `T` does not have a `foo` member, then the compiler will choose the second overload of `has_foo`.
- If `T` does have a `foo` member, the compiler will try the first overload but will fail since there is no matching `call_foo` function so it will again choose the second one and make a `std::false_type`.

Working code on ideone: http://ideone.com/erh93I.

You can put everything in a `class` if you want:

```
template <typename T>
class HasFoo {

    template <typename C>
    static int call_foo (int (C::*)(float));

    template <typename C>
    static std::true_type has_foo (decltype(call_foo(&C::foo)));

    template <typename C>
    static std::false_type has_foo (...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(has_foo<T>(0)){};
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot to mention: If the class has no foo at all, it should compile. Edit my question.

Comment: @Viatorus I have updated my answer - This is not as cleaner as the first version but this might be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with [`<experimental/type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) or  [`<boost/type_traits.hpp>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_detected.html)

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  auto foo() { return 0; }
};
struct B {
  auto bar() { return 0.0; }
};
struct C : public A {
  auto bAr() { return 0.0; }
};
struct D : public C {
  auto baR() { return 0.0; }
};

template <typename T>
using HasFoo_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo());

int main() {
  std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<HasFoo_t, A> << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<HasFoo_t, B> << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<HasFoo_t, C> << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<HasFoo_t, D> << std::endl;
}
```